# Add to cart for catalog ad on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I want to know if my understanding is right.

1. I want to run catalog ad on Facebook so I have installed the 3 event pixels (view content, add to cart, purchase)
2. But since there is no separate page for add to cart, I set up in a way that when user click on "add to cart" then, event code "add to cart" will be activated. (When on viewcontent page, I can see 4 pixels (pageview, viewcontent, addtocart, addtowishlist) but add to cart and purchase are shown as red. Then, When I clicked on cart button, After that, add to cart button becomes activated. (pixel helper) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTILb.png)
3. So I believe pixel have been installed correctly. But in my product feed Diagnostics in business manager, it shows as  something like this.

Is there any way that I can fix the issue? 
Thanks!

Comment: Business manager shows "must fix, content_type in add to cart is missing.

Comment: Where is your code?